# 403 error with controller via FreeMarker and spring

Tags: java, spring, controller, freemarker, http-status-code-403

I've created page *.ftl with some  tags and want to all this work with my specific controller.

I found that code written inside <#list el as set>  cant get controller

This works

```html
<div>
    <form action="/deckStatusDel" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="deckstatusid" value="${deckstatus1}" />
        <input type="hidden" value="${deck.id}" name="deckId">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <button type="submit">Delete status</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This doesn't

```html
<#list deck_statuses as deck_status>
    <div>
        <form action="/deckStatusDel" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="${deck_status.id}" name="deckstatusid">
            <span>${deck_status.status}</span>
            <button type="submit">Delete status</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <#else>
    empty
    </#list>
```

Controller code

```html
@PostMapping("/deckStatusDel")
    public String deckStatusDelete(
            @RequestParam Long deckstatusid,
            @RequestParam("deckId") Deck deck
    ) {
        deckStatusesRepo.deleteById(deckstatusid);
        return "redirect:/deck/"+deck.getId();
    }
```

The code from the list is getting and sending the correct id, but i get 403 error. Why?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so inconsiderate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second form you are missing a csrf token for authentication

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```